# How to partition results of MarkLogic 9 Optic Java API based on a field

Tags: java, xquery, marklogic, xquery-sql, marklogic-9

I am working on MarkLogic 9 Optic Java API to build a complicated query to perform some operations and return results. Below is the sample query built by my code (using com.marklogic.client.expression.PlanBuilder and com.marklogic.client.expression.PlanBuilder.ModifyPlan classes):

```
op:from-view(recordsSchema, recordsView).op:join-inner(op:from-view(productsSchema, productsView), op:on(op:view-col(recordsView, md5Digest), op:view-col(productsView, md5Digest))).op:join-inner(op:from-view(occurrencesSchema, occurrencesView), op:on(op:view-col(productsView, md5Digest), op:view-col(occurrencesView, md5Digest)))
.op:where(op:or(op:and(fn:contains(op:col(adDescription), SNACK FOODS), op:eq(op:col(pageNumber), 5)), op:and(op:eq(op:col(state), KY), op:eq(op:col(issue), 2018-01-21))))
.op:select((op:col(pageNumber), op:col(state), op:col(adDescription), op:col(issue)))
.op:order-by(op:desc(op:col(issue)))
```

Now I want to partition these results by a field, say newspaper, such that the number of rows in results are same but they are segregated based on supplied field, like:

```
Newspaper 1:
[row 1]
[row 2]
[row 3]
Newspaper 2:
[row 1]
[row 2]
```

and so forth.. 
In SQL, this can be done by using rank() function coupled with PARTITION BY. But I could not find an equivalent function in Optic API to do this.
Another possible way to do this could be to use additional 'order by' for this field (newspaper, in this example); find distinct values (eg., Newspaper 1, Newspaper 2); then run a select query with a where on the result set and use these subsets of results by holding them in variable and in some data structure like List. But this seems to be a little too complicated. I feel there should be a simpler way to do this.
ModifyPlan has a method groupBy() but it collapses all the rows matching the field into one row - while I want to retain total number of rows.
Any help/opinion on how to achieve this will be highly appreciated.
- Swati